# Recursive function call wrapped in anonymous function can't be found

Tags: javascript, recursion, anonymous-function

Note: This is mostly a theoretical practice.

```
function one() {
    return [1, function() { one(); }];
}
console.log((one()[1])());
```

The output gives `undefined`. Why?

Comment: What does your anonymous function return?

Comment: @Blender Asuming we are getting the whole snippet: Nothing (`undefined`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To split it up:

```
function one() {
    return [1, function() { one(); }];
}
console.log((one()[1])());

one(); // [1, function() { one(); }]
[1] // function() { one(); }
() // undefined
```

If you return `one()` it will return the array:

```
function one() {
    return [1, function() { return one(); }];
}
console.log((one()[1])());

one(); // [1, function() { return one(); }]
[1] // function() { return one(); }
() // [1, function() { return one(); }]
```

Comment: Or to put that all of that another way: the anonymous function doesn't explicitly return a value and thus returns `undefined` by default.

Comment: Argh I'm so sorry. I can't believe I forgot the return. Spent half an hour wondering if it was a JavaScript concept I didn't get. Thanks.

Comment: Woah woah woah, you can't just use `return one();` - wouldn't that cause an infinite recursiveness?

Comment: @Ian not it wouldn't, I suppressed it by wrapping it in an anonymous function. Here's what I was trying to accomplish: https://gist.github.com/chenglou/5689382

Comment: @chenglou Nevermind, you're clearly right. I don't know what I was thinking. I kept getting confused when trying to picture the execution order :)